# Using kappa coefficient to evaluate results of crowd sourcing

Tags: nlp, tagging, manual, voting, crowdsourcing

I have 4 sets of manually tagged data for 0 and 1, by 4 different people. I have to get the final labelled data in terms of 0 and 1 using the 4 sets of manually tagged data. I have calculated the degree of agreement between the users as 
A-B : 0.3276,
A-C : 0.3263,
A-D : 0.4917,
B-C : 0.2896,
B-D : 0.4052,
C-D : 0.3540.

I do not know how to use this to calculate the final data as a single set.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The Kappa coefficient works only for a pair of annotators. For more than two, you need to employ an extension of it. One popular way of doing so is to use [this expansion proposed by Richard Light in 1971](http://www.psych.umn.edu/faculty/waller/classes/meas14/Readings/Light1971.pdf), or to use the average expected agreement for all annotator pairs, proposed by [Davies and Fleiss in 1982](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2529886?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). I am not aware of any readily available calculator that will compute these for you, so you may have to implement the code yourself.

There is [this Wikipedia page on Fleiss' kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleiss%27_kappa), however, which you might find helpful.

These techniques can only be used for nominal variables. If your data is not on the nominal scale, use a different measure like the [intraclass correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation).